# Deleting Circles drawn on grids in C# Visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have drawn a grid on form 8 in on paint event of the form as shown below. I have written a class **drawRules** in which I mentioned to draw the vertical and horizontal lines based on input from the form.

```
 protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Graphics g;
        g = e.Graphics;
        Pen linePen = new Pen(System.Drawing.Color.CornflowerBlue);

        Int32 Num_of_Lines;
        Int32 gridLength;
        Int32 gridWidth;

        bool IsIntValue = Int32.TryParse(Form7.setValue2, out Num_of_Lines);
        bool IsIntValue1 = Int32.TryParse(Form7.setValue3, out gridWidth);
        bool IsIntValue2 = Int32.TryParse(Form7.setValue4, out gridLength);


       this.Size = new Size(Num_of_Lines * gridWidth, Num_of_Lines * gridLength);


        if (IsIntValue)
        {
            if (IsIntValue1)
            {
                if (IsIntValue2)
                {

                    drawRules.verticalRule vr1 = new drawRules.verticalRule(g, gridWidth, gridLength, Num_of_Lines);

                    //Draw horizontal line
                    drawRules.horizontalRule hr1 = new drawRules.horizontalRule(g, gridWidth, gridLength, Num_of_Lines);

                }
                linePen.Dispose();
                base.OnPaint(e);
            }

        }


    }
```

after this I want to draw circles wherever mouse is clicked for which I mentioned the mouse click event

```
private void Form8_MouseClick_1(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    int r1 = e.X;
    int r2 = e.Y;
    Graphics g2;
    g2 = this.CreateGraphics();
    drawRules newclass1 = new drawRules();
    newclass1.addcoordinate(r1, r2, g2);
}
```

**addcoordinate1** is a method in **drawRules** class which is called to draw circle. Also, i am writing those coordinates in a file

```
public void addcoordinate(int r1, int r2, Graphics g2)
{
    int gridWidth;
    int gridLength;
    int Num_of_Lines;
    bool IsIntValue = Int32.TryParse(Form7.setValue2, out Num_of_Lines);
    bool IsIntValue1 = Int32.TryParse(Form7.setValue3, out gridWidth);
    bool IsIntValue2 = Int32.TryParse(Form7.setValue4, out gridLength);

    Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle();
    PaintEventArgs arg = new PaintEventArgs(g2, rectangle);
    Pen redPen1 = new Pen(Color.Red, 3);
    DrawCircle(arg, redPen1, r1, r2, 8, 8);

    System.IO.StreamWriter objWriter;
    objWriter = new System.IO.StreamWriter("test.txt", true);
    objWriter.Write(r1);
    objWriter.Write(" ");
    objWriter.Write(r2);
    objWriter.WriteLine();
    objWriter.Close();
}

public void DrawCircle(PaintEventArgs e, Pen redpen1, int x, int y, int 
    width, int height)
{          
    e.Graphics.DrawEllipse(redpen1, x - width / 2, y - height / 2, width, height);   
    redpen1.Dispose();
}
```

*Now, I want to delete that circle, for which mouse is double clicked inside circle's area.*

Please suggest how to delete the circles without deleting the grids behind. I will be grateful, if someone help me in this.

Comment: As i remember if you use graphics the only way to erase something is to erase everything

Comment: How should I draw everything to just delete the drawn circles when asked by entering the coordinates which lie inside a circle.

Answer (score 0):

Don't draw in the code that gets executed when clicking the `Button`.
Save the coordinates and let the `OnPaint` methode handle it.
To remove your cirlces just remove them from the list.

```
private List<Point> circleCoordinates = new List<Point>();

public Form1()
{
  InitializeComponent();
}

public void addcoordinate(int r1, int r2)
{
  this.circleCoordinates.Add(new Point(r1, r2));
}

protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
  // linedrawing goes here
  foreach (Point point in this.circleCoordinates)
  {
    e.Graphics.DrawEllipse(Pens.Black, new Rectangle(point, new Size(10, 10)));
  }

  base.OnPaint(e);
}

private void Form1_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
  for (int i = this.circleCoordinates.Count() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
  {
    Rectangle ellipseRectangle = new Rectangle(this.circleCoordinates[i].X - 5, this.circleCoordinates[i].Y - 5, 10, 10)

    GraphicsPath path = new GraphicsPath();
    path.AddEllipse(ellipseRectangle);

    if(path.IsVisible(e.Location))
    {
      this.circleCoordinates.RemoveAt(i);
    }
    //invalidate form to trigger repainting
    this.Invalidate();
  }
```

Comment: OP was asking how he can remove one circle, and you just rewrote the code. *I want to delete that circle, for which mouse is double clicked inside circle's area*

Comment: the is no easz way to remove only a part of what has been drawn

Comment: oh i see. didn't got that will change my answer. Just a minute

Comment: I don't think that timer is a good idea.  That will cause the form to be repainted unnecessarily.  The form will be automatically invalidated if it is minimized or if another window passes in front of it.  `Invalidate` normally should only be called when the user does something that needs the form to be updated immediately.  In this case, when a circle is added or removed from the list, the `Invalidate` should be called.

Comment: Following lines of code are unable to draw the circles. Else everything is working fine. Please suggest.                                                           foreach (Point point in this.circleCoordinates)
  {
    e.Graphics.DrawEllipse(Pens.Black, new Rectangle(point, new Size(10, 10)));
  }

Comment: @ChrisDunaway sure having a `Timer` that calles `Invalidate` is a bit out of scope of the question. Will remove it in the answer. I normally implement it like this if i have something that is changing by time like moving circles XD. @user9315944 would you mind explaining what is not working? And please use `Code Tags`

Comment: The circles should be drawn on mouse click  and deleted on double click. But what is happening is, on every double click, single click event is also getting triggered. I searched and found out to use timer to differentiate single and double click. Please suggest if it is good for my code or something else has to be done.

Comment: Sure this would add a little bit of an performance inpact but couldn't you just remove the cirlce that was added on click again when double clicked?

Comment: The problem is, the circles are drawn considering the point clicked as the point on circumference of circle rather than center of the circle(ellipse is drawn with end points on intersecting lines from sides of Rectangle). So, each point which are very near gives different circles.e.Graphics.                                           DrawEllipse(Pens.Black, new Rectangle(point, new Size(10, 10)));

Comment: Rectangle ellipseRectangle = newRectangle(this.circleCoordinates[i], new Size(10, 10));                                                                       
 In the above code, Please help me to draw the circle by considering the mentioned points in list as centre rather than points on circumference.

Comment: `Rectangle ellipseRectangle = new Rectangle(this.circleCoordinates[i].X - 5, this.circleCoordinates[i].Y - 5, 10, 10);` just subtract half the width and height.